# Python Requests module - Strip back dictionary content

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-requests, python-3.7

I'm trying to call a web request from the link specified below (may have changed slightly depending when you read this) but I only want a specific part of it, it's all one line. From the part "build":"++Fortnite+Release-12.50-CL-13193885-Windows" I want to keep the ++Fortnite+Release-12.50-CL-13193885-Windows part.

What code would I need to use? This is what I have so far...

`url = "https://fortnite-api.com/v2/aes"
response = requests.get(url)
updateloop = response.json()["build"]`

> LINK: https://fortnite-api.com/v2/aes

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question doesn't have a specific focus and seems to be more general computing advice rather than coding help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
updateloop = response.json()["data"]["build"].replace("++Fortnite+Release-", "")
```

output

```
'12.50-CL-13193885-Windows'
```